# What is header caching good for in Spray?

Tags: scala, spray

We've been trying to track down a very elusive bug in one of our systems, where we get a `400 Bad Request` error after a number of requests to the server. We finally tracked it down as far as the HTTP Header caching in Spray, for some reason the `nodeCount` variable in `HttpHeaderParser` is being set to a value > 32k, which, since it later is converted to a `Short`, results in overflow.

We have fixed the problem by disabling HTTP header caching (`spray.can.server.parsing.header-cache.default = 0`). We have tried to make a reproducible minimal project but have been unable to.

My question is, what effects can we expect from disabling header caching entirely? I don't really understand why it is even necessary, since the headers have to be parsed anyway in every request (since the values might have changed). Is this to save memory by reusing `HttpHeader` objects?

Comment: Good point. I think we should discuss this in a ticket. Can you open one at https://github.com/akka/akka/issues because the same problem may occur in akka-http as well.

Comment: @jrudolph Done: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/18397